# Solving vector projection with python functions

Tags: python

Creating a function named that computes the projection of the b onto vector a. The function should work for vectors of any dimensionality.

**Conditions:**
 
- Vector b should only contains ones and should have the same dimension as a.

My following code does not seem to work. Any suggestions to changes?

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([3,-1])

def computeProjection(a): 
    b = np.ones(np.size(a))
    projection = ((np.dot(a,b))*a) / (np.linalg.norm(a))**2
    assert np.size(a) == np.size(b)
    return projection()

computeProjection(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

### `numpy.ndarray` is not callable

`projection` is a `numpy.ndarray`; just return it directly.

### Stylistically, the `assert` isn't needed.

It's good to check your assumptions, but you've explicitly told the arrays to be the same size (though you meant shape) -- no need to check.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def computeProjection(a):
...     b = np.ones(shape=a.shape)
...     projection = ((np.dot(a,b))*a) / (np.linalg.norm(a))**2
...     return projection
...
>>> a = np.array([3,-1])
>>> computeProjection(a)
array([ 0.6, -0.2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `return projection()` to `return projection`.
The `projection` is a parameter，not a function.